# Embedded JavaScript in PHP can not manipulate DOM in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom

I have a PHP to verify the HTML form (post method). If the value doesn't match, the error message should be added at the HTML page. I test the embedded JS script in console, it works. But it doesn't work in PHP. How can I fix it? Thank you

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
    <form action="http://localhost/submitTest.php" method="post">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
        E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
        <div id="submitField">
            <input type="submit">
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<?php

if ($_GET["name"] == 1 && $_GET["email"] == 2) {

    header('Location: http://localhost/table.html');

} else {

    $url = 'http://localhost/submitTest.html';

    echo "<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='0;URL=$url'>";

    echo "
    <script>
        var messageP = document.createElement('span');
        messageP.style.color = 'red';
        var parent = document.getElementById('submitField');
        parent.appendChild(messageP);
        messageP.innerHTML = 'not match';
    </script>";


}

?>
```

I want to do something like this[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEG4X.png)

Comment: Did you expect this to refresh to `/submitTest.html` first, and then execute your JavaScript in the context of _that_ page? That is not how it works, your JavaScript is currently looking for the element with ID `submitField` in the output of your `/submitTest.php` script - only there isn't any.